# "Complete action using" to send SMS not showing my app in android

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

I know this question is asked many times and I have tried all the solutions also. But still my app is not shown in the "Complete action using" list.

My myapp.manifest code:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.contactmanager.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                    <data android:scheme="sms" />
                    <data android:scheme="smsto" />
                </intent-filter>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

I have set permissions also but still i am missing something.May I need to restart my cell after installing this app?Or any settings i need to change?.Kindly help me to figure out the problem.

Comment: What version of Android are you testing on?

Comment: @ianhanniballake: android version: 2.3.5

Comment: Pardon me if I'm wrong, but do you need `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />` in the manifest file to be allowed to send SMS?

Comment: @ruparelia - I only ask because Android 4.4 totally changes SMS sending and you need to register as the default SMS app to send SMSs per [this Android Developer blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html) - you'll need to take that into consideration before publishing (although it is a different problem than this).

Comment: @jCuber: You may be right because I don't know perfectly but I read somewhere that I need to add permission..

Comment: @ianhanniballake: Yes you are right. More specifically,I am testing this app on Micromax ninja 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an `<intent-filter>` in your `<intent-filter>`, which isn't correct. Instead, you should have two `<intent-filter>` entries - one for the launcher intent and another for SMS sending:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.contactmanager.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="sms" />
            <data android:scheme="smsto" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: thanks for pointing out my mistake.I changed my code. But unfortunately still same result..

Comment: Thank you so much..I removed `<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />` and now it works perfectly..Thank you so much again...